# Create a Borderless Window with a drop shadow containing a WebView

Tags: java, css, javafx, webview

I have a Group which contains two nodes. The first node is a background, a simple rectangle rendering a drop shadow. The second node is a Region which renders a WebView. I want the WebView to appear "contained" within the rectangle so that it doesn't overlap the drop shadow, like in this screenshot, basically a borderless form with a drop shadow:

[image: Result]

I have the following code:

```
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
    Group region = new Group();
    scene = new Scene(region, 800, 600);
    scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/root.css").toExternalForm());
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

    Browser browser = new Browser();

    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(8, 8, stage.getWidth() - 16, stage.getHeight() - 16);
    rectangle.setFill(Color.WHITE);
    rectangle.setEffect(new DropShadow(12.0d, Color.color(0, 0, 0, 0.4)));

    region.setOnMousePressed(event -> {
        if (event.getSceneY() > 20) return;
        moving = true;
        xPos = event.getScreenX() - stage.getX();
        yPos = event.getScreenY() - stage.getY();
    });
    region.setOnMouseDragged(event -> {
        if (!moving) return;
        stage.setX(event.getScreenX() - xPos);
        stage.setY(event.getScreenY() - yPos);
    });
    region.setOnMouseReleased(event -> moving = false);
    region.getChildren().addAll(rectangle, browser);
}
```

And Browser.java:

```
class Browser extends Region {

    private final WebView webView = new WebView();
    private final WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();

    public Browser() {
        setPadding(new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20));
        getStyleClass().add("browser");
        webEngine.load(getClass().getResource("/index.html").toExternalForm());
        webEngine.setUserStyleSheetLocation(getClass().getResource("/reset.css").toString());
        getChildren().add(webView);
    }
}
```

And root.css:

```
.browser{
    -fx-padding: 20;
}
```

Nothing seems to work. I can't seem to get the result I'm looking for. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that because I was adding a child to a custom Region subclass (Browser), and then adding an instance of that Browser to my scene, it was causing issues with rendering it. Here's the code I used to fix the issue:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);

    BorderPane container = new BorderPane();

    // WebView instantiated elsewhere ...
    container.setCenter(webView);

    scene = new Scene(container, 800, 600);
    scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/root.css").toExternalForm());

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

    webEngine.load(getClass().getResource("/index.html").toExternalForm());
    webEngine.setUserStyleSheetLocation(getClass().getResource("/reset.css").toString());

    // Mouse Events ...
}
```

And my root.css:

```
.root {
    -fx-effect: dropshadow(gaussian, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 24, 0, 0, 0);
    -fx-background-insets: 24;
    -fx-padding: 24;
}
```